# create multiple svn repositories at once

Tags: svn, repository, svnadmin

I am migrating a bunch of existing projects (without version control) into svn.

I was wondering if there is a way to create multiple repositories at once on the command line.

`svnadmin create repo1 repo2 repo3` etc.

I realize the above wont work, since that is not the parameters expected.

I know this is probably more a case of a generic solution like

```
ls FileWithRepoNames | svnadmin create ______
```

but was not sure how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
for i in `cat FileWithRepoNames`;
do
    svnadmin create $i;
done;
```

Ls is used to list the contents of a directory. I assumed you wanted to read the names from a file, in which case you need to use cat.

Note that "cat" in this context this will split the file into seperate words, not lines.

Comment: Worked perfectly, exactly what I was after. Thank you :)